# Angle of contact in a capillary tube?

Tags: capillary-action

Why the angle of contact of water and glass is 0. According to the capillary action why the angle of contact of water and glass is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Contact angle depends upon the adhesive forces, 
(contact angle :is the angle between the glass and water by drawing tangent to the contact point, generally contact angle for pure water and Glass surface is zero.) the reason contact angle is zero it depends upon this cohesive and adhesive forces, like if you replace the water with oil angle would be different because the force between glass and oil molecules is different. Now for water a pure contain only two type of forces, force between water molecule and Glass and water molecule. If you add impurity like NaCl which is high insoluble you will see contact angle will not zero.

Comment: Do you mean highly soluble?